# Cannot call a method from a Javascript ES6 constructor

Tags: javascript

I have the following "class" definition:

```
class MyClass{
     constructor(name, surname, age){
         this.Name=name;
         this.Surname=surname;
         this.FullName=getName();
         this.Age=age;

     }
     getName(){
         this.FullName=this.Name+" "+this.Surname;
     }
}
let myClass=new MyClass("Jose","Suarez",22);
```

The thing is that when the constructor is executed the method getName is called and inside the method this.FullName has the right value, but when it jumps to the constructor again (this.Age), this.FullName becomes undefined.

Could you explain me why doesnt keep the right value?

Thanks a lot

Jose.

Comment: It should be `this.getName()`, and the `getName()` function needs a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getName()` *sets* the value of `this.FullName`, but it doesn't return anything. In Javascript, when you set a variable to the result of a function with no return, that variable will be undefined. So what happens in your code is that `getName()` sets the value of `this.FullName`, but then your constructor sets `this.FullName` equal to the value that `getName()` returned, which is undefined.

You can fix this in two ways. One is to have `getName()` actually get and return a value, as the name implies:

```
class MyClass{
     constructor(name, surname, age){
         this.Name=name;
         this.Surname=surname;
         this.FullName=this.getName();
         this.Age=age;

     }
     getName(){
         return this.Name+" "+this.Surname;
     }
}
let myClass=new MyClass("Jose","Suarez",22);
```

The other option is to simply call `this.getName()` without setting its result to a variable, like so:

```
class MyClass{
     constructor(name, surname, age){
         this.Name=name;
         this.Surname=surname;
         this.getName();
         this.Age=age;

     }
     getName(){
         this.FullName=this.Name+" "+this.Surname;
     }
}
let myClass=new MyClass("Jose","Suarez",22);
```

Edit:
As Pampattitude pointed out, there is a difference between `getName()` and `this.getName()`. You must use `this` when referencing member functions from inside an object, just as you were doing with the variables in the object.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:
 - first, your `getName` method should be called via `this`, i.e. `this.getName`; else, it will search for a `getName` function at the global scope instead of the one from your class.
 - second, you don't return any value from the `getName` method! Instead of assigning `FullName`, try returning the result:

```
getName(){
    return this.Name+" "+this.Surname;
}
```

This will return the result of the concatenation, and set your `FullName` attribute accordingly via the

```
this.FullName=this.getName();
```

line.

Answer (score 0):

Because `getName` does not have a return statement, hence it returns `undefined`.

```
 getName(){
     return this.Name + " " + this.Surname;
 }
```

and use `getName` correctly

```
this.Fullname = this.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return full name from getName(), like this:

```
class MyClass{
     constructor(name, surname, age){
         this.Name=name;
         this.Surname=surname;
         this.FullName=this.getName();
         this.Age=age;

     }
     getName(){
         return this.FullName=this.Name+" "+this.Surname;

     }
};
let myClass=new MyClass("Jose","Suarez",22);
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your code a little better.